# Heroku postgres hobby basic memory limit

Tags: node.js, database, postgresql, heroku, heroku-postgres

I'm planning to make a NodeJS app with Express and an SQL database and upload it all to Heroku. I am going to get the Postgres Hobby Basic plan.

On the Heroku website it says that my database is limited to 10 000 000 rows, but I don't know if there are any memory limits. For example if I can't store more that 0.5 GB of data on my database. I would be grateful if someone could tell me is my database limited only by the 10 000 000 rows limit, or is there a memory limit as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Storage (disk) and memory (RAM) are different things. [Dynos have a memory limit](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/limits#dyno-memory), e.g.

> free, hobby and standard-1x have 512 MB

Heroku Postgres plans have different types of limits by tier. [Hobby tier limits are based on row count](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgres-plans#hobby-tier). [Standard](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgres-plans#standard-tier) and above tiers have no row limits, but they do have storage limits. For example, Standard-0 plans have a storage limit of 64 GB.